# How to split a CLI command in Azure Devops over multiple lines? (Running on Windows)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

I am running the following in a CLI task on Azure Devops (inline)

```
rem Create the Service Plan
call az appservice plan create --resource-group %RESOURCE_GROUP% --name %SERVICE_NAME% --sku B1
```

Whch works just fine. However, I'm having to scroll to see the whole thing and I have other commands which are even longer. So I'm trying to split it over multiple lines so I can see more clearly what is going on.

Looking at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-create-and-configure-database-cli?toc=%2Fcli%2Fazure%2Ftoc.json) it looked like the solution was to put a backslash on the end of each line. So I tried:

I've tried:

```
rem Create the Service Plan
call az appservice plan create \
--resource-group %RESOURCE_GROUP% \
--name %APP_SERVICE_NAME% \
--sku B1
```

Which didn't work. I then read something that recommended the back-tick/back-quote at the end of each line:

```
rem Create the Service Plan
call az appservice plan create `
--resource-group %RESOURCE_GROUP% `
--name %APP_SERVICE_NAME% `
--sku B1
```

This also didn't work. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Never mind. Worked it out. Turns out you need to use '^'

```
rem Create the Service Plan
call az appservice plan create ^
--resource-group %RESOURCE_GROUP% ^
--name %APP_SERVICE_NAME% ^
--sku B1
```

Answer (score 19):

The character that you need to use to specify that the command is split over multiple lines, depends on the environment in where the CLI command is run.
In other words, it depends on the `scriptType` property of the `AzureCLI@2` command.

- Powershell/Powershell Core:  use a backtick `
- bash: use backslash `\`
- batch: use accent circonflexe `^`

Comment: The real answer. Awesome

Answer (score 10):

Ensure the *backtick* you use is the correct one (it's immediately to the left of "1" on my Microsoft keyboard).

I was trying to use a ' instead of ` in the failed attempt as the CLI docs were reading made it hard to distinguish.

Comment: backslash \ and the hat ^ do not work for me either but back tick does `

Answer (score 0):

from azure cloud shell, type AZ, then copy paste the az command with \ for multiple line will not work.
but there is a fix, you click on the + sign like a adding a folder sign, it will bring a full page Azure Cloud Shell window, change to Bash from the pull down (default is Poweshell), then you see prompt changed to name@Azure:~$, now you can use az commend with \ for multiple lines.

Comment: to clarify my prior post, just to the top left corner in the cloud shell, select bash, then the multiple line command with \ will work

Comment: [florin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15341506) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66503568) saying "harry's answer is actually the better one; you need to change to a bash shell instead of PS"